# Magento 2 : In which element are image properties configured in etc/view.xml?

Tags: magento2

In which element are image properties configured in etc/view.xml?

Answer (score 3):

In `etc/view.xml`

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <vars module="Module_Name">
        <var name="Var_Name">#Value</var>
    </vars>
</view>
```

Extend `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image` And Get Value of Variable

```
$this->getConfigView()->getVarValue('Module_Name', 'var_name');
```